# Is there a way to convert JWK to x.509 cert in Apex salesforce

Tags: jwt, crypto

Is there any way in APEX Salesforce to convert JWK to x.509 cert so that the Crypto class can be used to verify another JWT ?

Comment: I don't think it can be done through Apex. Have you tried with OpenSSL commands?